# Download big file from server with range requests

Tags: javascript, php, http, download, request

I need to download files through multiple streams in browser. I run the php server which is able to process Range Requests, so it returns the number of bytes requested. But how to download parts of file in multiple streams to then combine them in one is a question. I do have control over requests.

Comment: Please provide code showing what you've tried so far and ask a specific question.

Answer (score 0):

Just combine them together, here is code sample:

```
var part1, part2
function rangeRequest1() {
      var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlHttp.open("GET", "http://localhost:3000/zuckjet.pdf", true);
      xmlHttp.responseType = "blob";
      xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Range", "bytes=0-18000");
      xmlHttp.onload = function() {
      part1 = new Blob([oReq.response], { 
        type: 'application/pdf' 
      });
      // Pseudocode： part2  = another rangeRequest's response
      download()
};
function download() {
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    var blob = new Blob([part1, part2]);
    link.download = 'zuckjet.pdf';
    link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    link.click();
    URL.revokeObjectURL(blob);
}
```